# Solution for non numeric dynamic input field names in front end

Tags: javascript, php, html, database-design

I have students, student_subject, subjects, modules and module_results tables.

Students Table

```
| id | name  |
|----|-------|
| 1  | John  |
| 2  | Sara  |
| 3  | Smith |
```

Subjects Table

```
| id | name        |
|----|-------------|
| 1  | Science     |
| 2  | Mathematics |
| 3  | English     |
```

Modules Table

```
| id | subject | name              |
|----|---------|-------------------|
| 1  | 1       | Science_mod_1     |
| 2  | 1       | Science_mod_2     |
| 3  | 2       | Mathematics_mod_1 |
| 4  | 2       | Mathematics_mod_2 |
```

Student_subject Table

```
| id | student_id | subject_id |
|----|------------|------------|
| 1  | 1          | 1          |
| 2  | 1          | 2          |
| 3  | 2          | 1          |
| 4  | 3          | 1          |
```

Results Table

```
| id | student_subject_id | module_id | result |
|----|--------------------|-----------|--------|
| 1  | 1                  | 1         | 45     |
| 2  | 1                  | 2         | 25     |
| 3  | 2                  | 3         | 65     |
| 4  | 2                  | 4         | 45     |
```

There are separate forms to insert students (with selecting subjects), subjects (with adding modules) and results. I got a problem creating the form to add results for a student.

The form consists of form inputs listing down all the modules of the subject to enter results. For a specific student, the form to insert results may look like this(after looping the students subjects modules). The name attribute contains the Module table id value. I add the name to this value because In the database I need to have reference for the Module table in the database.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="1" required>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="2" required>
</form>
```

I want to know this approach is correct or wrong to add results to students? 
If not what are the changes I have to do in database and forms.